# Spring Boot Test: Expected request don't persist using ExpectedCount.manyTimes()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, spring-boot-test

I'm trying to run some integration tests on my code and I use a `MockRestServiceServer` from `spring-boot-test` in order to set up the expected requests.

I have one call that is called many times while running my test, but it seems not to persist during the test. My test looks like this:

```java
@Test
    void getHealthStatus() {
        try {
            RequestBuilder request = get("/actuator/hc").contentType("application/json");

            MockServerBinder.bindPersistentThingworxPropertiesCall(
                    mockServer,
                    requestTo(new URI(String.format("%sProperties/TestProp", thingworxUrl))),
                    objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new PingResponse(DashboardIndicator.HEALTHY, 200))
            );

            DashboardStatusModel expectedResult = new DashboardStatusModel();
            expectedResult.addResult("spring",service.getAppHealth());
            expectedResult.addResult("thingworx", service.getThingworxAvailability());

            assertOpenUrl(request);
            MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/actuator/hc").contentType("application/json"))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andReturn();

            DashboardStatusModel actualResult = objectMapper.readValue(result.getResponse().getContentAsString(), DashboardStatusModel.class);

            assertEquals(expectedResult.getResults().get("spring"), actualResult.getResults().get("spring"));
            assertEquals(expectedResult.getResults().get("thingworx").getStatus(),actualResult.getResults().get("thingworx").getStatus());
            assertEquals(expectedResult.getResults().get("thingworx").getData().get("url"), actualResult.getResults().get("thingworx").getData().get("url"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail("Unable to perform REST call on GDP-API", e);
        }
    }
```

*As additional information:*

- *`mockServer` is created in a superclass like this:*

```java
protected static MockRestServiceServer mockServer;
    @BeforeEach
    public void configureMockServer() {
        mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restTemplate).ignoreExpectOrder(true).build();
    }
```

- *`MockServerBinder.bindPersistentThingworxPropertiesCall()` is a helper class that looks like this:*

```java
public static void bindPersistentThingworxPropertiesCall(MockRestServiceServer mockServer, RequestMatcher request, String responseJSONasString){
        mockServer.expect(ExpectedCount.once(), request)
                .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
                .andRespond(withStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .body(responseJSONasString));
    }
```

- *`assertOpenUrl(request);` is a function that checks if a URL doesn't have any authentication by using a `MockMVC`:*

```java
public void assertOpenUrl(RequestBuilder request){
        try{
            mockMvc.perform(request).andExpect(status().isOk());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail("Unable to perform REST call on GDP-API", e);
        }
}
```

When I run this test, the `expectedResult.addResult("thingworx", service.getThingworxAvailability());` will be able to use the `MockRestServiceServer`, but the `assertOpenUrl(request);` line will fail, because `MockRestServiceServer` doesn't expect anymore calls to the endpoint binded in `MockServerBinder.bindPersistantThingworxPropertyCall()`. This does not happen if I Copy & Paste `MockServerBinder.bindPersistantThingworxPropertyCall()` under the existing one, so I think it's a problem with how I binded the request in the first place.

From what I understand `ExpectedCount.manyTimes()` should keep this request during the test.
Is this not true or is there another way I should bind my request so that it stays available during the entire test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PEBCAK issue.

As you can see in the `bindPersistentThingworxPropertiesCall()`, I actually **didn't** use `ExpectedCount.manyTimes()`. I didn't catch that. Changed it and now it works.